# Easy way to look up assembly qualified names

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, reflection

Is there a tool or visual studio feature that makes it easy to look up the *Assembly Qualified Name* of a `Type` in the GAC?

I would like to check to see if a Type is available at runtime for a system, in which I need that name and I am interested in sometime easier then writing some throw away code to look it up.

Comment: it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599575/enumerating-assemblies-in-gac

Comment: @Massimiliano-Peluso, maybe, i'd like to not reinvent the wheel just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use reflector, you can a: load from the GAC, and b: get this in two parts - the assembly name (including signature) is on the *assembly* node in the tree, for example (displayed at the bottom of the page):

> System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

and of course the type name is at the leaf level:

> System.Xml.XmlNode

That still leaves the awkward nested types, but just add + instead of .

Not ideal, perhaps, but pretty workable.