# Performing gacutil operations programmatically in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

How can I perform the operations done by gacutil, like installing assemblies or listing the contents of the GAC, programatically in C#?   Or to put it another way, is gacutil layered on top of a public API that I can access from C#?

I'm currently running under .Net Framework 4.0 and using Visual Studio 2010, but I'll be upgrading to VS 2012 and .Net 4.5 in the near future.   I don't like using command-line programs when I have a GUI alternative because I'm a fumble-fingered typist so I thought I'd write my own GUI-based utility for some things that gacutil does.    I know there are some on the web but they're old or only spottily-maintained so I'd rather write my own.

Comment: You'll find C# source code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2611435/17034).

Answer (score 4):

You can easily add dll to GAC using `Publish` class. Add reference to `System.EnterpriseServices`

```
System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish publish = new System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish();
publish.GacInstall("dll path");
```

[enumerating assemblies in GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137008/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-assemblies-i-can-reference-on-my-machine)