# how to determine .net assembly dependency in code

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, system.reflection

How to determine what other dll/exe is being used by a particular .net dll/exe? In simple words i want to find out the dependencies of a particular .net dll/exe which is in Global Assembly Cache. How can it be read via system.reflection?

Comment: Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().  These are *known* dependencies, reflection code in the assembly can add unknown ones.  You'd have to dig though embedded resources as well.  COM interop and pinvoke adds more yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) pointed out in his comment, you can use the `GetReferencedAssemblies` method to retrieve the referenced assemblies of a dll (i.e. the "known" dependencies):

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management, Version=6.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");
var referencedAssemblies = assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();
foreach (var referencedAssembly in referencedAssemblies)
{
     Console.WriteLine(referencedAssembly.FullName);
}
```

The `Assembly.Load()` method will load an Assembly from the GAC if you fully qualify it with the `Version`, `Culture`, and `PublicKeyToken`. [[reference]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279341/c-how-to-load-assembly-from-gac)

Comment: Also can we load simply gac dll without providing the version?

Comment: No, you have to supply the version of the assembly. Otherwise you will receive a `FileNotFoundException`. You may be able to discover those additional details, however, by attempting to browse through the GAC's contents (such as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599575/enumerating-assemblies-in-gac)